# Objective-c stackflow

Tags: objective-c

I am building a small application with the following structure:

AppDelegate: Loads the menu Controller

MenuController:
Controls 4 menu items that are created in the xib file
A xib file with the following structure
- view
  - Image View (Background)
  - Second View (MiddleView)
  - Navigation Bar
    - segmentedControl

TrackController: Is getting load by the MenuController

I load the page with the following code:

```
    TracksController *currentView = [[TracksController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TracksController" bundle:nil];

    [MiddleView addSubview:currentView.view];

    [currentView release];
```

The errormessage what I got is:
2009-11-17 11:25:17.336 Par23[1883:20b] *** -[NSCFType playNow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x48361e0
2009-11-17 11:25:17.337 Par23[1883:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFType playNow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x48361e0'

playNow is a IBAction in TracksController.

I think my problem is my logica. And that the view within the view isn't the way how you should work.
This because it isn't a problem within the button IBAction.

I hope I explained it enough

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is that you haven't made the case mistake you made in your post. `playNow:` is not equal to `PlayNow:`.

Second thing I would check is does the TracksController or the button which connects to `playNow:` have multiple connections attached. You check this in IB, using the connections panel.

If those don't help, does TracksController trigger playNow programmatically at all?

Maybe, since you've stacked up views, a method selector is getting passed to the wrong viewcontroller?

Comment: In my question is mistype. it is playNow and that is correct.
It also doensn't have multiple connections.

I think the mainproblem is that I use a segmentedcontrol to do the same things a tabbarcontrol does. The reason that I choose for this, is that I need the space. So probably this gives weird things